# Comparing a string to substrings in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, substring

I currently have an array of substrings and I'm trying to find matches in a long string.  I currently loop through the array and compare each element to the string, but once the array gets bigger this is taking a lot of time.  Is there a faster way to do this?

```
$substring_list = array('/item/', '/mail/', '/product/');
$string = 'http://www.mystore.com/wishlist/item/';

foreach ($substring_list as $substring) {
    if (strpos($string, $substring) !== false) {
        $result = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This finds the substring `'/item/'` in the string `'http://www.mystore.com/wishlist/item/'` and returns false.

I have searched through all the questions here, but I can only find how to do it the other way (substring matching in an array of strings).

Comment: It's unclear what the objective is, exactly. You want to find _all_ matches of `$substring` inside `$string`? Or just that `$substring` exists inside `$string`? i.e. It's unclear if your goal is to find the actual position of the string or just that it happens to be there. Providing sample input and expected output vs. actual output is also helpful in trying to narrow down the crux of your question.

Comment: If you get the data from the database, let the database do the work.

Comment: On that note, it's also entirely unclear how the database is involved in this problem at all. As such it's exceedingly difficult to identify what a _faster_ solution might look like without knowing which aspects of the problem are _slow_.

Comment: I pull the array from the database, that is all, but as the array gets bigger, this loop can take a lot of time.  I was wondering if there was maybe a single statement to look in the array instead of looping through each element of the array. I've edited the code to better explain what I'm doing.

Comment: Assuming MySQL you could do something like `WHERE LOCALE(your_db_field, 'http://www.mystore.com/wishlist/item/') > 0`